# PHP read txt from specific line to the end

Tags: php, file-io

In the following, `$mensaxe` reads the second line of a .txt file:

```
function getMessageList(){
  $this->messageList = array();
  if ($handle = @opendir($this->messageDir)) { while ($file = readdir($handle)) { if (!is_dir($file)) { $this->messageList[] = $file; } } } 
    rsort($this->messageList);
    return $this->messageList;}   

function displayGuestbook($page=1){
  $list = $this->getMessageList();

  $startItem = ($page-1)*$this->itemsPerPage;
  if (($startItem + $this->itemsPerPage) > sizeof($list)) $endItem = sizeof($list);
  else $endItem = $startItem + $this->itemsPerPage; 

  for ($i=$startItem;$i<$endItem;$i++){
    $value = $list[$i];
    $data = file($this->messageDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    $fecha  = trim($data[0]);
    $titulu = trim($data[1]);
    $mensaxe = trim($data[2]);  
        unset ($data['0']);
        unset ($data['1']);
        unset ($data['2']);

        echo "<div id=\"comentariu\">
              <div>$fecha</div>
              <div>$titulu</div>
              <div>$mensaxe</div>
              </div>"; }
```

How can I make it read from **the second line** to the end?

Comment: your `unset()` doesn't need the quotes. What does `$data` look like?

Comment: "data" is a TXT file, i want this code to read date from first line, title from second line, and a message from the third line onwards, but my proble is that by the moment it only reads the third line :(

Comment: I was referring to the variable `$data` it at least has `$data[0]`, `$data[1]`,`$data[2]`as items for direct access. Just wanted to know what the complete structure was like.

Comment: $data doesn't have any other mention in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hard understand your question but maybe you want this. mensaxe will receive all  items of array but 0 and 1

```
$mensaxe = array_slice($data, 2);
```

You can trim all the array by array_map function:

```
$mensaxe = array_map(trim, array_slice($data, 2));
```

**UPDATE**

to output  $mensaxe as a text,  you can make string with 
 instead of former newlines

```
echo "<div id=\"comentariu\">
              <div>$fecha</div>
              <div>$titulu</div>
              <div>".implode('<br>', $mensaxe)."</div>
              </div>"; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @splash58. As you can see I'm not very good at php. My problem when using $mensaxe = array_slice($data, 2); is that it only prints the word "array" instead of the message.

Comment: @Kagarin What do you what do with $mensaxe - only output as text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) like so:

```
$mensaxe = array_slice($data, 2);

// ...
echo "<div>$titulu</div>";

echo "<ul>";
foreach($mensaxe as $value) {
    echo "<li>$value</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```